# How to install IIS Server on ubuntu

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, ubuntu, iis

I have two machines, one of them it's operating system is windows as a Client and other machine is ubuntu as a Server. I have an asp.net project which I made on visual studio on windows machine so I want to use ubuntu machine as a server for my web application.

Comment: IIS is Windows only; You may like to investigate Apache + http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

IIS is related to microsoft. It can't be run on any linux. Try apache. 
Their is also no other way that you can Bridge between apache and IIS.

Comment: Just as an addition: You can install mod_mono to run it in the apache. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/